# java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: ISO-8859-8, text/xml

Tags: java, xml, servlets, xmlhttprequest, websphere

I work in an organization that started moving its workstations to Windows 10.

One of our oldest systems that works correctly in Windows 7 fails to work properly in Windows 10.

When the browser sends an http request, an  java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException occurs on the server.

In Browser side:

```
req= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
req.open("POST", url, false);
req.send(content); // content contain xml request
```

In server side:
Seems to me on command:

```
aResp.setContentType("text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-8");
```

The exception:

```
E com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils parseQueryString unsupported exception
                                 java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: ISO-8859-8, text/xml
    at java.lang.StringCoding$DecoderCache.getDecoder(StringCoding.java:143)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.getDecoder(StringCoding.java:384)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:496)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:242)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:271)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils.parseQueryString(RequestUtils.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.parseQueryStringList(SRTServletRequest.java:2364)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.parseParameters(SRTServletRequest.java:2334)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getParameter(SRTServletRequest.java:1822)
```

Anyone have any idea what the difference is between Windows 7 and 10? Or rather what is missing in Windows 10 that is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

`ISO-8859-8` is not one of the [standard charsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) that Java *needs* to support, i.e. which are guaranteed to be found (unless you have a corrupted installation).

In your case, the difference seems to be in the Windows 10 environment. I would check first that it has support for `ISO-8859-8` (I don't know how though, I'm not a Windows user). It may need to be installed/enabled separately.

If you're **certain** that your Windows 10 does support that encoding, then it's a problem with Java not being able to make the connection between the two, and you'll probably have to delve into [charset providers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html), but let's hope you don't have to go there.

Comment: I checked in regedit --> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Charset
and this encoding exist there

Answer (score 0):

Are the two systems using the same version of Java?

Note that iso-8859-8 is not listed as a supported encoding here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: Both systems are invoking  the same server by HTTP protocol and the server has not changed. 
This encoding came to support the Hebrew language beyond windows-1255

Comment: OK, so the issue is that one of the client systems is requesting an encoding that the server does support, while the other client system is requesting an encoding that the server does not support? I think I understand the problem better now (but can't help with a solution).

Comment: What do you mean not supported? It's listed as being in the extended set at `lib/charsets.jar`. But for the international version, so presumably the installation has the European version instead, and `charsets.jar` needs to be added to the installation.

Comment: I have no idea what the word "supported" means, especially when the company in question is Oracle. I was merely pointing to a published list of encodings that Oracle describe as "supported".

Comment: Also, I didn't say "not supported". I said "not listed as a supported encoding". Clearly its absence from one particular list of supported encodings isn't strong evidence that it's "not supported", and the fact that something isn't "supported" doesn't mean it doesn't work.